# command.execute is not a function

Tags: discord.js

i was trying to make an afk command with discord.js
i keep getting command.execute is not a function, and i have no idea how to fix it. please help!

````
client.on("message", async message => {
  if (message.author.client) return;
  if (message.channel.type === "dm") return;

  let prefix = config.prefix;
  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  let command = messageArray[0].toLowerCase();
  let args = messageArray.slice(1);

  if (message.content.includes(message.mentions.members.first())) {
    let mentioned = client.afk.get(message.mentions.users.first().id);
    if (mentioned) message.channel.send(`**${mentioned.usertag}** is currently afk. Reason: ${mentioned.reason}`);
  }
  let afkcheck = client.afk.get(message.author.id);
  if (afkcheck) return [client.afk.delete(message.author.id), message.reply(`you have been removed from the afk list!`).then(msg => msg.delete(5000))];

  if (!command.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  let cmd = client.commands.get(command.slice(prefix.length));
  if (cmd) cmd.run(client, message, args);
});```
````

Answer (score 0):

In the scope of your function, `command` is the variable that is equal to `messageArray[0].toLowerCase();`, which is a string and does not have a `execute` method.

I guess you are trying to call the `execute` method of an object you called command, try to change the naming of your variables to avoid overriding the one you need.